# Minimum number of steps to reach white cell

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, coordinate-systems

I came across this problem in a recent interview.

We are given a chessboard considered in coordinate plane with origin at leftmost lower corner and leftmost lower corner is black coloured. Each cell of board has width and height $l$ and we are at point $P(x,y)$. We move in steps $(dx, dy)$ i.e. $(x,y) => (x+dx,y+dy)$. Given the value of $x, y, dx, dy$ and $l$, We need to find minimum value of k for which $(x+kdx,y+kdy)$ will lie in white cell. Each value, x, y, dx, dy, l are integers.

I think we need to do it by concept of gcd. But, I am not able to do maths to reach upto solution. How to solve such problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

First, to simplify the algebraic expressions, assume that all distances have been divided by $l$. (So, in the working below, the $x$ represents your  $\frac{x}{l}$) .

Let $x=U+X$ and $y=V+Y$ where $U$ and $V$ are the whole number parts of  $x$ and $y$, respectively. If the difference between $U$ and $V$ is odd, then you are already in a white square. So suppose the difference is even.

To get to a white square, the minimum $|k|$ will then be the least of $$\frac{X}{dx},\frac{1-X}{dx},\frac{Y}{dy},\frac{1-Y}{dy}.$$

Returning to your initial variables these quantities are

$$\frac{X}{dx},\frac{l-X}{dx},\frac{Y}{dy},\frac{l-Y}{dy}.$$

Comment: Is that the minimum $|k|$?

Comment: Yes thanks - that would be a more precise way of stating the result.

Comment: Does this answer assume we can move $(dx,0)$ or $(0,dy)$?  I thought the OP question said we can only move $(dx, dy)$ i.e. both directions together.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, but all x, y, dx, dy, l are integers. I have mentioned that in question now.

Comment: Re. @antkam query, the answer has **not** assumed separate movements. The moves are (dx,dy) but which side is reached first will depend on which of the quantities in the answer are least.

Comment: Re. AnkitSharma comment. Providing you are not requiring $k$ to be an integer the solution does not require any modification. However, if you do require $k$ to be an integer then substantial changes are needed because some moves may 'miss' white squares.

Comment: @S.Dolan - you are right that if $k$ can be non-integer than your solution is valid when moving $(dx,dy)$.  I have assumed $k$ must be integer, and in that case, as your later comment pointed out, the solution doesnt work.

Comment: This is incorrect. Suppose in the original setup we have $\ell=4, X=Y=6, $ and $(dx,dy)=(3,4)$. Then $(\frac{X}{dx},\frac{\ell-X}{dx},\frac{Y}{dy},\frac{\ell-Y}{dy})=(\frac23,\frac23,\frac12,\frac12)$, so your solutions suggests $k=1$ is the answer. However, $(6+1\cdot 3,6+1\cdot 4)=(9,10)$ and $(6-1\cdot 3,6-1\cdot 4)=(3,2)$ are both in the interiors of black squares, so this cannot be right.

Comment: @MikeEarnest. You are quite right - that final sentence should not have been in the answer. As I put in a comment to the OP. "However, if you do require k to be an integer then substantial changes are needed because some moves may 'miss' white squares." – S. Dolan 19 hours ago

Comment: @MikeEarnest. As you may have noticed no  "integer" restriction  was mentioned in the original question.